# Closed form for matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, closed-form

Let Q be a n by n positive definite or positive semi definite matrix and g be a vector in $R^{n}$.

Is there a closed form to get x?

$g^{T}Q^{k}g = x(g^{T}Qg)$

where k is a some integer number.

Comment: Please use LaTex

Comment: If it's positive definite, can't you just use eigendecomposition of $Q^k$ and then divide by $g^TQg$?

Comment: If the matrix Q is too huge to get eigendecomposition, do you have other suggestions?

Comment: If $Q$ has unique largest eigenvalue $\lambda$, then for almost all $g$, for large $k$ we know that $x$ grows (or decays) like $\lambda^{k}$.

Comment: Isn't $x=\frac{g^TQ^kg}{g^TQg}$ closed enough (provided $g^TQg\neq 0$)?

Comment: I want $x$ that is a function of k. Can $||g||_2$ or $||Qg||_2$ or $trace(Q)$ be involved to get $x$?

Comment: I don't think so. You can though compute it recursively from the quantities of the form $q^TQq/q^Tq$.